# Json data is send null

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to send json data from the view to the controller in asp.net mvc. But the data is null.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSignUp').click(function () {

        var email = ('#txtEmail').val();
        var username = ('#txtUsername').val()
        var password= ('#txtSifre').val();



        $.ajax({
            url: '/User/SignUp',
            data: { email: email, username: username, password: password},
            datatype: 'Json',
            type: 'Post'

        }).done(function () {
            $('#success').show(500);
        })

    })
})
```

controller code: data : email,username ,password.
data is null.
debug result : email=null, username=null,password=null

```
 public ActionResult SignUp(string email,string username,string password)
    {
        var data = db.Users.Where(x => x.Nick == username || x.Email==email).SingleOrDefault();
        Users user= new Users();
        if (data== null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username is valid");
        }
        else
        {
            uye.Nick = username;
            uye.Email = email;
            uye.Password= password;

            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("HomePage","Home");
    }
```

Comment: You have `datatype: 'Json',` but your method does not return json, so that would throw an error. Your method has `RedirectToAction()` but ajax calls cannot redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page)

Comment: try `JSON.stringfy({ email: email, username: username, password: password})`

Comment: @ElmerDantas that should normally only be required if the contentType was set to JSON, but otherwise jQuery will just serialise it to normal form fields, which MVC should accept quite happily.

Comment: Does the network tab in your browser show the ajax request, and show the values that are sent, in the request body? Are they what you expect? If not, check that you're reading the values from the form fields properly. Also, what kind of button is "btnSignUp"? Is it within a form? If so, does it have "type='button'" defined? If not, it's potentially posting back normally before it can do the ajax call and you need to prevent the default postback

Comment: @ADyson I know but I can´t see anything wrong in his code, maybe route configuration...that's why "try"

Comment: @ElmerDantas better to ask more questions IMO than to suggest something based on insufficient evidence, especially when we know the normal behaviour in the situation, as I described.

Comment: try `$('#btnSignUp').click(function (e) {e.preventDefault()` and add `$` before `('#txtEmail').val()` like this `$('#txtEmail').val()`

Comment: thanks work it. :)